How to create a Flutter or React app for personal use on iPhone without publishing on the App Store?
I have a MacBook and an iPhone, and I would like to know if it's possible to create an app using Flutter or React Native (I preferred flutter) for personal use without needing to publish it on the App Store or Play Store. My goal is to run the app on my iPhone without depending on being on the same Wi-Fi network. Is there a way to do this for free?
In the past, I created a Flutter app and had to connect the iPhone to the MacBook via cable. Is there a way to do this now for free without using the same network or cables?

Try this
https://medium.com/@itskaranzzz/how-to-install-ipa-file-directly-to-iphones-tabs-without-using-laptop-desktop-e645c36125d2

now you can't unless you have apple developer account or using jailbreak
